# Vector is returned empty

Tags: c++, vector

Note: I **can't** post full source due to various reasons, but I'll give the basic ideas.

```
class Whatever{
private:
std::vector<int> vector;

public:
std::vector<int> getVector() {
    return vector;
}
```

if I was to call getVector(), the previously filled vector would be empty.
e.g.

```
whatever Class;
std::cout << "\n\n" << Class.getVector().size();
```

This would return **0**.

Any advice?

**note:** the original vector does indeed get filled, but the contents do not transfer over to the new vector.

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the problem. And beware that you return a copy of the vector when you call `getVector()`. That is probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: You forgot to fill the vector.

Comment: And I would rename the private var from vector to v to run out of shadowing problems. It is asking for trouble.

Comment: Honestly, I guessed I might need to fill the new vector, but I was under the impression it would just return the already filled vector.

Comment: No, I mean you forgot to fill the original vector.

Comment: We can only guess as you do not provide the filling code.

Comment: No, the vector IS full. I made sure to check before posting. Kinda sucks that I can't post the full source.

Comment: Kinda sucks that you seem unwilling to create a small test-case and expect everyone to guess what is wrong with your secret code.

Comment: Well, I did write it very quickly just to get the point across.

Comment: It's pretty simple: in the example you provided, you never fill the vector. If that's not the problem for you, update the example to reflect your problem more accurately.

Comment: `class Whatever{` ... `whatever Class;` You got to be joking. This "code" is sloppier than my sloppy joe, and I like my sloppy joe *very* sloppy.

Answer (score 3):

> f I was to call getVector(), the previously filled vector would be
>   empty.
>
> whatever Class; std::cout << "\n\n" << Class.getVector().size();
>
> This would return 0. Any advice?

You forgot to fill the vector.

```
class Whatever{
private:
  std::vector<int> v_;

public:
  Whatever ( int n) : v_( n) {}
  std::vector<int>& getVector() {
                 ^^^ // most probably you want to avoid copy
      return v_;
  }
```

};

---

You original definition:

```
std::vector<int> getVector() {
    return vector;
}
```

**will always return a copy** of what vector is equal to.

You say:

> note: the original vector does indeed get filled, but the contents do
>   not transfer over to the new vector.

I am sure you do it this way:

```
Whatever w;
std::vector<int> v = w.getVector();
v.push_back( 107);
//... etc
std::vector<int> v2 = w.getVector();  // empty
```

Comment: if that's really what he's doing ... wow. Why even bother having the vector be a private class variable at that point.

Comment: can you see another explanation for: the original vector does indeed get filled, but the contents do not transfer over to the new vector? If vector REALLY gots filled even the copy returned from getVector would have had some elements, right?